# curl 401 Unauthorized error

Tags: curl, http-status-code-401, unauthorized

As shown in image when i am trying to run **https://www.example.com/Push_Order.php?orderId=1562** It gives me **401 Unathorized** error. But when I run this Url in browser it run well.

Any Idea where is my mistake or what i am missing?

[image]

**PHP Curl Code**

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("https://www.example.com/Push_Order.php?orderId=1562");

curl_setopt($ch);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

and this Push_Order.php file contains only insert query.

Comment: Sure, your mistake is that you have no code and your current question has nothing to do with php.

Comment: @Inurosen the file contains insert query only.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears you have authorization enabled in Apache on your server but you don't realize it at the moment because your browser is caching the username and password for you.

You have to set the `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option like so:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("https://www.example.com/Push_Order.php?orderId=1562");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myusername:mypassword");

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

(The empty `curl_setopt($ch)` was weird and a no-op at best anyway.)

In the command line it should work just like this (including the username and password in the URL):

```
curl https://myusername:mypassword@www.example.com/Push_Order.php?orderId=1562
```

Comment: Yes you are right.. I had placed .httaccess file.. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this error message coming from my Apache2 web server and it took me a little while to diagnose, so I want to document what was wrong for anyone researching the same problem as I had, and landing here.

I assumed incorrectly that my Apache was running fine and I really had an authorization problem, as that is what the message implies. The reality was I had syntax errors in my Apache config files.

If a local `curl` gives you this

[image]

(character for character the same, give or take a URL and port number,) you might want to check you can happily run

```
service apache2 reload
```

before investigating authorization too heavily!